# hex строка и проблема с первым 0x при получении bytearray

Tags: python, hex, bytearray

Если hex строка

```
hex_string = '1314FFAAF810'
```

то полный порядок:

```
bytearray.fromhex(hex_string)
```

Но если hex строка:

```
hex_string = '0x1314FFAAF810' # с нулем впереди то не проходит
```

Как работать с hex строками где впереди 0x?

Чтение из базы:

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(...);
cursor = cnxn.cursor() 
cursor.execute("select hex_value from dbo.hex_data") 
row = cursor.fetchone()
```

`row` объект pyodbc который содержит 0x1314FFAAF810 и это надо перевести в bytearray

Comment: что `hex_string[2:]` возвращает? (если этого не знали, то стоит любой текст по Питону прочитать, чтобы не тратить своё время зря) Откуда ввод и в каком виде может приходить?

Comment: Из MS SQL Server (varbinary)

Comment: покажите строчку, которая это значение читает из дб. [mcve]

Comment: Добаил, обновив вопрос.

Comment: `row` однозначно вводу не равен. Попробуйте: `print(ascii(row))`¶ Почему данные как hex, а не как сами байты пишутся?

Comment: Работает, также как и просто print(row) 1314 это число FFAA тоже

Comment: вы разницу между `(b'aa',)` и `'aa'` понимаете? Просто приведите буквальный вывод

Comment: да первое 170 второе aa

Comment: вы о чём? чему равен [`print(ascii(row))`](https://ideone.com/weYwu4)?¶ Почему данные как hex, а не как сами байты пишутся?

Comment: (b'\x13\x14\xff\xaa\xf8\x10', )

Comment: Прекрасно, только при чём тут тогда оригинальный вопрос? Где вы взяли эти строки (с и без '0x')? Прочтите заголовок Вашего вопроса.

Comment: Удалил руками 0x чтобы проверить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
h = hex_string[2:] if hex_string.startswith('0x') else hex_string
data = bytes.fromhex(h)
```

---

Если у вы получаете из базы данных байты: `row = (b'\x13\x14\xff\xaa\xf8\x10', )`, тогда:

```
data, = row
```

это  уже последовательность байт (неизменяемая). Если вам нужна изменяемая последовательность байт, тогда `a = bytearray(data)`.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сначала интерпретировать строку, как число:

```
>>> bytearray(int('deadbeaf', 16).to_bytes(4, byteorder='big'))
bytearray(b'\xde\xad\xbe\xaf')
>>> bytearray(int('0xdeadbeaf', 16).to_bytes(4, byteorder='big'))
bytearray(b'\xde\xad\xbe\xaf')
```